# micro-controller based plant watering system

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, atmelstudio

I am trying to build an automatic plant watering system using ATmega16. We are using moisture sensor for our project. The following is the image of the moisture sensor we have used.
[image]

The circuit diagram is as follows:
[image]

The following is the code fragment we used:

```
#include<avr/io.h>
int adc(void);
void pump(void);
int adc_value;
int main(void)
 {
  DDRC=0x01;                          //Defining PC0 as output
  ADCSRA=0x87;                    //Setting the mode of operation
  ADMUX=0x00;                     //Selection of channel and bit alignment
  while(1)
   {
     adc_value=adc();                //reading moisture level
     pump();                               //Pump activator routine
   }
   return 0;
 }

int adc(void)
 {
   int lower_bits,higher_bits,result;  
   ADCSRA|=(1<<6);              //Turning on conversion
   while(ADIF==0);
   lower_bits=ADCL;
   higher_bits=ADCH;
   result=lower_bits|higher_bits<<8;         //Accessing converted value by shifting
   return result;
 }

void pump(void)
 {
  if(adc_value>=700)                                //Pump ON trigger point
   {
     PORTC|=(1<<0);
   }
  else if(adc_value<=600)                        //Pump Off trigger point
   {
     PORTC&=~(1<<0);
   }
 }
```

Is there anything wrong in the code? because after burning it, i am getting low voltage for wet soil and high voltage for dry soil from the analog sensor input which is ok … but the problem is, i am always getting high voltage at PC0 in borh cases.. there in no change in the values for dry and wet soil.. in such case where is the actual problem.. is there anything wrong in the circuit design or in the code?  And one more thing,can anyone please tell me the proper way of measuring the output value I am getting from PC0 which in turn is switching on/off the pump?

Answer (score 1):

You don't clear the `ADIF` flag before the conversion starts. It will always read 1 after the first time through. Add a line to clear the flag (by writing a 1 to the flag bit. Yes, writing a 1 makes it 0. It is not a regular register).

Also, you are not reading the flag correctly. `ADIF` is a bit in a byte, so you need to read the byte with a bitmask. (You were actually testing is `2==0`, as `ADIF` is defined to be 2.)

```
int adc(void)
 {
   int lower_bits,higher_bits,result; 

   ADCSRA |= (1 << ADIF);  // <<<<<< Add this to clear flag

   ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);  //ADCSRA|=(1<<6);  //Turning on conversion

   while(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF) == 0);  //while(ADIF==0); <<<<<< Change this

   lower_bits=ADCL;
   higher_bits=ADCH;
   result=lower_bits|(higher_bits<<8);         //Accessing converted value by shifting
   return result;
 }
```

Actually, you were already inadvertently clearing the flag. If it was 1, then `ADCSRA` has a 1 in the `ADIF` position, and it gets written again. But it is still better to be more explicit in what you mean to do. As well, you can combine the two actions into one assignment.

```
int adc(void)
 {
   int lower_bits,higher_bits,result; 
   ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC)|(1 << ADIF);  //Turn on conversion and clear flag
   while(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF) == 0);  //wait for flag
   lower_bits=ADCL;
   higher_bits=ADCH;
   result=lower_bits|(higher_bits<<8);         //Accessing converted value by shifting
   return result;
 }
```

I can't confirm the rest of your code and wiring is correct, because I haven't looked, and this is the first obvious problem. Fix it, and update your question if you still have problems.

Comment: can you  please tell me the proper way of measuring the output value I am getting from PC0 which in turn is switching on/off the pump? @UncleO

Comment: @user3114849 I don't understand your question. You can hook an oscilloscope or a voltmeter directly between PC0 and ground. You could also connect to the junction between the diode, the coil and the transistor. Then it would read the opposite of PC0. When PC0 is 0 V, the junction will be 12 V. When PC0 is 5 V, then junction will be 0 V. (But these are not programming questions. Expect the pedants to arrive soon to close down your question!)